# Change the width of a scrollbar

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

Is it possible to change the width of a scroll bar on a form.  This app is for a touch screen and it is a bit too narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the scrollbars is controlled by Windows. You can adjust the scrollbar width in Display Properties and it will affect all windows on the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This is a Windows Forms application?  I was able to make a very fat and thick scrollbar by adjusting the "Width" property of my scroll bar control.

[image: Fat Scroll Bar]

Is your scroll bar something you have programmatic access to (i.e. it is a control you added to the form)?